# Is it possible to auto trigger snippets in Rstudio?

Tags: r, triggers, latex, rstudio, code-snippets

With Rstudio you can add [customized snippets](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets) but always they should be triggered using TAB or SHIFT-TAB depending on if you are in R or Rmd file.

Is it possible just to trigger the snippet by typing the sequence of characters?

For example, just by typing `dm` it will create an equation environment without the TAB or SHIFT-TAB intervention.

I'm thinking in something like [this](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/) especially for typing  documents fast with a lot of math and code mixed.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The page in your second link requires TAB to trigger the snippet.  I imagine that's where RStudio got the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, in the second link, I think he uses TAB only for demonstration purposes. For real work I think he auto triggers the command with some characters combos (e.g. mk, dm, //, etc) and nothing else. 

A very ideal case will be replicate something like this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7gpx0h-BuU) but in Rstudio.

Answer (score 1):

According to the RStudio devs this feature is not possible right now.

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6834